# Any good advice about how to avoid import cycle in Go?

Tags: dependencies, go, circular-dependency

I'm working on a Go project for a month. The good thing is Go is really highly efficient. But after a month of development I've already got thousands lines of code and many `packages`. To avoid import cycle is a major issue for me that anytime I got a import cycle error, I have no idea where the problem may be at first time.

The Go compiler also only have very simple notice that always not good enough to locate issue quickly like: `main.go:7:3: import cycle not allowed`. It will only help you to know which file may cause the problem but nothing more deeply. Since `import` relationship just become more and more complex while code grows, I'm eager to know how to avoid import cycle more efficiently in Go. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}' <import-path>
```

Will show import dependencies for package at `<import-path>` - or in current directory if `<import-path>` is left empty. Alternatively

```
go list -f '{{join .DepsErrors "\n"}}' <import-path>
```

hopefully shows some useful information in your case. See also the output of

```
go help list
```

for additional information about the go list tool.

Comment: Definitely good to know, didn't even know about go list, actually.

Comment: Newer versions of go give you more information about where the import cycle is coming from

Answer (score 44):

To complement on jnml's answer (which helps "debug" circular references problems), you can use [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to break those cycles, coupled with dependency injection. For an application, I always try to follow the guidelines of the [Clean Architecture](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) - see [here](http://manuel.kiessling.net/2012/09/28/applying-the-clean-architecture-to-go-applications/) for a Go-specific example - and I find that Go's "non-declarative implementation" of interfaces (that is, you don't have to explicitly say `type MyStruct struct implements IfceSomething`) makes this very simple.

So, if you have packages `A -> B -> C -> A`, you create `InterfaceA` (some relevant name, obviously, more behaviour-related than package-related :) in package C and make it depend on this interface instead of on package A, and you make sure package A "implements" this interface.

Then you just have to provide a concrete implementation of A to C at some point (many possibilities here, I usually do this "glue" code in the main package that knows about all dependencies).

Answer (score 12):

> Since import relationship just become more and more complex while code
>   grows, I'm eager to know how to avoid import cycle more efficiently in
>   Go.

Another option is to visualize the dependencies in your project. This can be done with CLI tool [godepgraph](https://github.com/kisielk/godepgraph).
You can install it with:

```
go get -u github.com/kisielk/godepgraph
```

And then use it for finding import cycles in your app with help of another CLI tool [graphvis](http://graphviz.org/).
Having this tools you can visualize package dependencies:

```
godepgraph -s path/to/my/package | dot -Tpng -o godepgraph.png
open ./godepgraph.png
```

to find cycles in my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an aside to using the go list tool, which may confirm dependencies you already know about, from a architectural view you want to make sure that your dependency tree is deep enough that you can find out about cycles by building out sub-components. If there is a import cycle in a module then the cycle that exists should be clear. There should be enough modularity (tree depth) that moving these dependencies around works seamlessly.

```
Model -> Field  (Uses A) -- Needs to import "System"
Model -> System (Defines A) -- But needs to import "Field"
----------Move type A Struct A.go to top of module----------
----------This is what the Model Dir looks like now---------
Model -> A
Model -> Field
Model -> System
```

Now dependencies have been separated and the children can use A freely. This may not help with visualizing the dependencies or be a nice tool based solution, but once again, if you decouple your logic enough and build out the sub-components you should converge on the cycle pretty quickly. Otherwise if you're using a tree visualizer I would say that's a last resort and a result of poor design/not enough sub-components.