# How to find where is the import cycle in go code?

Tags: go

I am fed up with the error

```
main.go:10:5: import cycle not allowed
```

The bug does not give information, where is the dependency cycle and does not even tell which file is the problem. Is there a way I can find out the dependency cycle or dependency diagram in go? As the codebase goes large its very difficult to deduce this.

Comment: You are not alone, this is listed as a Go Issue:
https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4292

Comment: And it was fixed a few weeks ago. So you can build the 'go' tool from source, or wait til a new release comes out with that fix in it.

Comment: There's no single _"which file is the problem"_ in a cycle (modulo a package importing itself).

Comment: @MatrixFrog Awesome,I will recompile and see then

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good advice about how to avoid import cycle in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168601/any-good-advice-about-how-to-avoid-import-cycle-in-go)

Comment: This question asked 6 years ago. I use the last version golang but the error msg don't tell me which file

Answer (score 1):

And the collective answer based on comments above:

Its a known issue, recently fixed so look out for a new release or compile the go tool from source.

(Contributed by: @MatrixFrog, @infantDev, @jnml and @nemo)