# Registering packages in Go without cyclic dependency

Tags: go, packaging, cyclic-dependency

I have a central package that provides several interfaces that other packages are dependent on (let us call one `Client`). Those other packages, provide several implementations of those first interfaces (`UDPClient`, `TCPClient`). I instantiate a `Client` by calling `NewClient` in the central package, and it selects and invokes the appropriate client implementation from one of the dependent packages.

This falls apart when I want to tell the central package about those other packages, so it knows what clients it can create. Those dependent client implementations also import the central package, creating a cyclic dependency which Go does not allow.

What's the best way forward? I'd prefer not to mash all those implementations in a single package, and creating a separate registry package seems overkill. Currently I have each implementation register itself with the central package, but this requires that the user knows to import every implementation in every separate binary that makes use of client.

```
import (
    _ udpclient
    _ tcpclient
    client
)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The standard library solves this problem in multiple ways:

### 1) Without a "Central" Registry

Example of this is the different hash algorithms. The [`crypto`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/) package just defines the [`Hash`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#Hash) interface (the type and its methods). Concrete implementations are in different packages (actually subfolders but doesn't need to be) for example [`crypto/md5`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/) and [`crypto/sha256`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/).

When you need a "hasher", you explicitly state which one you want and instantiate that one, e.g.

```
h1 := md5.New()
h2 := sha256.New()
```

This is the simplest solution and it also gives you good separation: the `hash` package does not have to know or worry about implementations.

This is the preferred solution if you know or you can decide which implementation you want prior.

### 2) With a "Central" Registry

This is basically your proposed solution. Implementations have to register themselves in some way (usually in a package `init()` function).

An example of this is the [`image`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/) package. The package defines the [`Image`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) interface and several of its implementations. Different image formats are defined in different packages such as [`image/gif`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/), [`image/jpeg`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/) and [`image/png`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/png/).

The `image` package has a [`Decode()`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/) function which decodes and returns an [`Image`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) from the specified [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). Often it is unknown what type of image comes from the reader and so you can't use the decoder algorithm of a specific image format.

In this case if we want the image decoding mechanism to be extensible, a registration is unavoidable. The cleanest to do this is in package `init()` functions which is triggered by specifying the blank identifier for the package name when importing.

Note that this solution also gives you the possibility to use a specific implementation to decode an image, the concrete implementations also provide the `Decode()` function, for example [`png.Decode()`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#Decode).

---

So the best way?

Depends on what your requirements are. If you know or you can decide which implementation you need, go with #1. If you can't decide or you don't know and you need extensibility, go with #2.

...Or go with #3 presented below.

### 3) Proposing a 3rd Solution: "Custom" Registry

You can still have the convenience of the "central" registry with interface and implementations separated with the expense of "auto-extensibility".

The idea is that you have the interface in package `pi`. You have implementations in package `pa`, `pb` etc.

And you create a package `pf` which will have the "factory" methods you want, e.g. `pf.NewClient()`. The `pf` package can refer to packages `pa`, `pb`, `pi` without creating a circular dependency.

Comment: May I have more clarification on solution #2? Is the 2nd last paragraph, an `init` functions refers to each `init` function in central and implementations?

Comment: Great answer. So, I think #2 doesn't work for me because to use your example, my `image` packages `image/*` need to import `image` because parts of the interface they're implementing includes other interfaces in `image`. I think you saw this, because #3 directly addresses this.

Comment: @JohanSJA I'm referring to the subpackages: png decoder will only work and be available for the `image.Decode()` function if the `init()` functions of the `image/png` package have been executed which register the png decoder at the registry of the `image` package. This (calling `init()` functions of `image/png`) is triggered if you import the package (even with just the `_` blank identifier): `import _ "image/png"`.

Comment: @MattJoiner Yes, that is correct. Solution #3 solves this by moving the "factory" functions to a new package therefore `pi` does not need to import the implementation packages `pa` and `pb`.

Comment: Thank you for addressing this unreasonably contentious issue.

Answer (score 4):

> Those dependent client implementations also import the central package

They should rely on another package defining interfaces that they need to rely on (and that are implemented by the first central package).

This is usually how an import cycle is broken (and/or using [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)).

You have more options described in "[Cyclic dependencies and interfaces in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20394211/6309)".

[`go list -f`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16169115/6309) can also help visualizing those import cycles.

Comment: How does `go list -f` help?

Comment: @MattJoiner See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16169115/6309: it shows  show import dependencies for a given package.