# Instantiating an interface implementation based on a dynamic configuration value

Tags: go

New Gopher here, coming from Java land.

Let's say I have a some generic storage interface:

```
package repositories

type Repository interface {
  Get(key string) string
  Save(key string) string
}
```

I support multiple different backends (Redis, Boltdb, etc) by implementing this interface in separate packages. However, each implementation has unique configuration values that need to be passed in. So I define a constructor in each package, something like:

```
package redis 

type Config struct {
 ...
}

func New(config *Config) *RedisRepository {
  ...
}
```

and

```
package bolt

type Config struct {
  ...
}

func New(config *Config) *BoltRepository {
  ...
}
```

`main.go` reads a json configuration file that looks something like:

```
type AppConfig struct {
  DatabaseName string,
  BoltConfig *bolt.Config,
  RedisConfig *redis.Config,
}
```

Based on the value of `DatabaseName`, the app will instantiate the desired repository. What is the best way to do this? Where do I do it? Right now I'm doing some kind of horrible factoryfactory method which seems very much like a Go anti-pattern.

in my main.go, I have a function that reads the above reflected configuration values, selecting the proper configuration (either `BoltConfig` or `RedisConfig`) based on the value of `DatabaseName`:

```
func newRepo(c reflect.Value, repoName string) (repositories.Repository, error) {
    t := strings.Title(repoName)

    repoConfig := c.FieldByName(t).Interface()

    repoFactory, err := repositories.RepoFactory(t)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return repoFactory(repoConfig)
}
```

and in my `repositories` package, I have a factory that looks for the repository type and returns a factory function that produces an instantiated repository:

```
func RepoFactory(provider string) (RepoProviderFunc, error) {
    r, ok := repositoryProviders[provider]
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("repository does not exist for provider: %s", r)
    }
    return r, nil
}

type RepoProviderFunc func(config interface{}) (Repository, error)

var ErrBadConfigType = errors.New("wrong configuration type")

var repositoryProviders = map[string]RepoProviderFunc{
    redis: func(config interface{}) (Repository, error) {
        c, ok := config.(*redis.Config)
        if !ok {
            return nil, ErrBadConfigType
        }
        return redis.New(c)
    },
    bolt: func(config interface{}) (Repository, error) {
        c, ok := config.(*bolt.Config)
        if !ok {
            return nil, ErrBadConfigType
        }
        return bolt.New(c)
    },
}
```

bringing it all together, my `main.go` looks like:

```
cfg := &AppConfig{}
err = json.Unmarshal(data, cfg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

c := reflect.ValueOf(*cfg)

repo, err := newRepo(c, cfg.DatabaseName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

And yes, the second I was done typing this code I recoiled at the horror I had brought into this world. Can someone please help me escape this factory hell? What's a better way to do this type of thing -i.e selecting an interface implementation at runtime.

Comment: In broad strokes, the approach in the question is similar to how the database/sql and image packages handle this issue.  See the implementations of [Open](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Open) / [Register](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Register) in database/sql.

Comment: Related / similar question: [Registering packages in Go without cyclic dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271440/registering-packages-in-go-without-cyclic-dependency).

Comment: The problem originally arose because I had a cyclical dependency -very helpful links guys, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need dynamic registration? It seems like the list of backends is already baked into your server because of the `AppConfig` type, so you may be better just writing the simplest possible factory code:

```
func getRepo(cfg *AppConfig) (Repository, error) {
    switch cfg.DatabaseName {
    case "bolt":
        return bolt.New(cfg.BoltConfig), nil
    case "redis":
        return redis.New(cfg.RedisConfig), nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown database: %q", cfg.DatabaseName)
}

func main() {
    ...
    var cfg AppConfig
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &cfg); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to parse config: %s", err)
    }
    repo, err := getRepo(&cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("repo construction failed: %s", err)
    }
   ...
```

}

Sure, you can replace this with generic reflection-based code. But while that saves a few lines of duplicated code and removes the need to update `getRepo` if you add a new backend, it introduces a whole mess of confusing abstraction, and you're going to have to edit code anyway if you introduce a new backend (for example, extending your `AppConfig` type), so saving a couple of lines in `getRepo` is hardly a saving.

It might make sense to move `getRepo` and `AppConfig` into a `repos` package if this code is used by more than one program.

Comment: I think you're right, i'm just overcomplicating things. It would make sense to have a registry/factory and dynamically configuration repos if this were a library, but since all supported backends are already 'baked in' to the server as you say, there really is no point.