# Use of internal package not allowed

Tags: go, go-build

I'm trying to build and run a repo (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master) but this error keeps popping up and still I haven't found a solution to this.

```
consensus.go:12:2: use of internal package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/pkg/identity not allowed
```

This is just one of many files that give this error.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong since this repo is suppose to be working.

Go version :

```
go version go1.13.5 linux/amd64
```

OS : Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Internal packages](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit) (packages that are inside a folder that has an `internal` folder in their path) can only be imported from packages rooted at the parent of the `internal` folder.

E.g. a package `pkg/foo/internal/bar` can be imported by the package `pkg/foo/internal/baz` and also from `pkg/foo/baz`, but cannot be imported by the package `pkg` nor can it be imported by `pkg/bar`. This is by design. This is so big, complex packages can be broken into smaller packages without having to expose internals.

You have to treat internal packages as "private" or non-existent from the "outside".

See related: [Can I develop a go package in multiple source directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899203/can-i-develop-a-go-package-in-multiple-source-directories/45902409#45902409)

Read more about internal packages at [Command go: Internal Directories](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Internal_Directories).

Internal packages are a compiler restriction. If you want to expose them (if you want to use an internal package) in your own project, you have to remove the `internal` folder, and then of course you have to change the imports (import paths) too.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Since it won't be the case to move the files I want to build, from the way I understand is that I should change the GOPATH src folder such that the library becomes allowed. I hope I'm right @icza.

Comment: @Tuan Internal packages are a compiler restriction. If you want to expose them, you have to remove the `internal` folder, and then of course you have to change the imports (import paths) too.

Answer (score 2):

```
├── module1
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── internal
│   │   └── pkga
│   ├── pkg1
│   └── pkg2
└── module2
    ├── go.mod
    └── pkg1
```

The internal/pkga package in module1 can be imported by the pkg1 and pkg2 packages in module1. But it cannot be imported by the pkg1 package of module2.
The standard convention for internal packages: For packages with internal keywords in the export path, only the parent directory of internal and its child packages are allowed to be imported, and other packages cannot be imported.
In the example given by the teacher, the parent directory of internal is module1, and the child packages of the parent directory are module1/pkg1 and module1/pkg2. Therefore, in this example, internal can only be imported from these three places.
The above convention is verified by the Go compiler, and internal is a special directory name that the Go compiler can recognize when compiling the program. If the verification fails, an error will be reported.

Answer (score -3):

**Change** fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/widget
**To** fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget

Just remove the **/internal** from the package path inside the code editor

Comment: This question has already been answered and is fairly old.  You should only post an additional answer if it adds something to the conversation (e.g. a new technology that changes the answer).