# Firebase Appcheck Golang Admin SDK requires use of internal package externally in its API

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-admin, firebase-app-check

Current issue [on their Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/issues/572#issuecomment-1647210504).

First, I believe the Firebase documentation for how to use AppCheck with the Golang Admin SDK is wrong [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend#go). It says you need to create a new `appcheck.Client` directly via method off of your `firebase.App`, but this method doesn't exist (anymore?).

```golang
func main() {
    app, err := firebaseAdmin.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }

    appCheck, err = app.AppCheck(context.Background()) // <-- here
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/yourApiEndpoint", requireAppCheck(yourApiEndpointHandler))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

So, instead, I've referred to
Firebase's `appcheck` package [here](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/appcheck) which says you now need to create a new instance via this method instead:

```golang
func NewClient(ctx context.Context, conf *internal.AppCheckConfig) (*Client, error)
```

This, in theory, should work. However, note the use of an `internal` module.

We can try using `NewClient(...)`, and will be able to provide its first arg of `context.Context`, but won't be able to provide a value for its second arg of type `*internal.AppCheckConfig` [because it's internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342373/use-of-internal-package-not-allowed).

Does anyone have a fix for this? Or, perhaps, I'm overlooking the correct way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your GitHub repro steps show your import as `"firebase.google.com/go"`, which is the `v1` version of that module. Was that also the case when you tried to use the `AppCheck` method? In the `v4` major version (which the cited Firebase documentation example uses), the [App.AppCheck](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4#App.AppCheck) method should exist.