# How to manage cyclic dependencies when have interface and its implementation in different packages

Tags: go, cyclic-dependency

I have my project structure looks like this:

Structure of code:

```
hypervisor
├── hypervisor.go
├── hyperv
│   └── hyperv.go
└── virtualbox
    ├── vbox.go
    └── vboxprops.go
```

Source code:

```
//hypervisor/hypervisor.go
package hypervisor

type Hypervisor interface {
    Start(vmName string) error

    ListMounts(vmName string) ([]MountPath, error)

    //....
}


type MountPath struct {
    HostPath  string
    GuestPath string
}


func detect() (Hypervisor, error) {
    return &virtualbox.Virtualbox{}, nil  // <<1 HERE
}

// ... other code
```

And have another (nested) package :

```
//hypervisor/virtualbox/vbox.go
package virtualbox

type Virtualbox struct {
}

func (*Virtualbox) Start(vmName string) error {
    return vboxManage("startvm", vmName, "--type", "headless").Run()
}

func (*Virtualbox) ListMounts(vmName string) ([]hypervisor.MountPath, error) { // <<2 HERE
    // ....
} 

// ... other code
```

And as seen, of course, such code leads to `import cycle not allowed` . because of:

1. `hypervisor` pcakge referencing `virtualbox.VirtualBox` type
2. `virtualbox` package referencing `hypervisor.MountPath` type

I know if I move the struct `MounthPath` to another package would solve the issue, but I don't think is the correct solution design-wise.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Registering packages in Go without cyclic dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271440/registering-packages-in-go-without-cyclic-dependency/29272910#29272910)

Comment: I went through it quickly and didn't notice that answer resides thier. Thanks you 

Answer (score 0):

One of easiest way I would do is to separate entities into `entities` package for example (in this case: the `Hypervisor` and `Virtualbox` struct are entities or whatever you want to call it).
This is most common design I think, so every struct that inner packages use will not cause cyclic deps.
Example of usage: all `time` package structs are on top package level. `time.Time{}`, `time.Duration{}`, etc. `time.Duration` does not sit on `time/duration` package.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions from Dave Cheney to define [interfaces by the caller](https://dave.cheney.net/practical-go/presentations/gophercon-israel.html#_let_callers_define_the_interface_they_require) will avoid cycle dependencies in most cases. But this will only solve flat data models. In your case, you have nested entities ie., HyperVisor has fucntion which returns MounthPath. We can model this in two ways

1. Define MouthPath in separate package (like you suggested). In
   addition, defining the interface in the virtualbox package will help
   in long term to provide alternative implementation for Hypervisor.
2. Let virtualbox define both Hypervisor and MounthPath as interface. One disadvantage is that the hypervisor implementing package use virtualbox.MouthPath interface to satisfy the interface when passed like below.

//hypervisor/hypervisor.go

```
package hypervisor

type Hypervisor struct{
     someField []virtualbox.MountPath
}

type MountPath struct { // this can be used as virtualbox.MountPath
    hostPath  string
    guestPath string
}

func (m *MountPath) HostPath() string { return m.hostPath }
func (m *MountPath) GuestPath() string { return m.guestPath }

func detect() (Hypervisor, error) {
    return &virtualbox.Virtualbox{}, nil  // <<1 HERE
}
```

And have another package (Need not be nested)

```
//hypervisor/virtualbox/vbox.go
package virtualbox

type Hypervisor interface {
    Start(vmName string) error

    ListMounts(vmName string) ([]MountPath, error)

    //....
} 

type MountPath interface {
        HostPath()  string
        GuestPath() string
}

type Virtualbox struct {}

func (*Virtualbox) Start(vmName string) error {
    return vboxManage("startvm", vmName, "--type", "headless").Run()
}

func (*Virtualbox) ListMounts(vmName string) ([]MountPath, error) { // <<2 HERE
    // ....
}
```

Comment: MountPath need to be used by other hypervisor implemntations as well. So it cannot be part of the virtualbox package